# Waiting for execlp

Tags: c, unix, operating-system, fork, signals

I am making a program in which I have to fork 4 programs which will then exec . My problem is how to wait for child that do exec. Wait() does not work when child do exec

Answer (score 2):

> My problem is how to wait for child that do exec. Wait() does not work when child do exec

Assuming you are talking about the `wait(3)` function, it works *perfectly* fine for any child, regardless of whether the child performs `execve(2)` system call or not.

Since you apparently want to wait for 4 children, you may be also interested in the `waitpid(3)`.